# Get all values from an element

Tags: xslt

Given the below XML, how can I get both values with a single statement?
I tried /root/set/name/. with no luck.

```
 <root>
  <set>
   <name>John</name>
  </set>
  <set>
    <name>Jane</name>
  </set>
 </root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the output as `John Jane` use this XSLT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this applied on,

```
<root>
  <set>
   <name>John</name>
  </set>
  <set>
    <name>Jane</name>
  </set>
</root>
```

will give `John Jane`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use for-each. You can get each name in bellow manner.

```
<xsl:for-each select="root/set">
 <xsl:value-of select="name" />&nbsp;
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: I would like the output to be John Jane.